# What meaning does the length of a Word2vec vector have?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am using Word2vec through [*gensim*](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) with Google's pretrained vectors trained on Google News. I have noticed that the word vectors I can access by doing direct index lookups on the `Word2Vec` object are not unit vectors:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from gensim.models import Word2Vec
>>> w2v = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
>>> king_vector = w2v['king']
>>> numpy.linalg.norm(king_vector)
2.9022589
```

However, in the [`most_similar`](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/0.12.4/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1153-L1213) method, these non-unit vectors are not used; instead, normalised versions are used from the undocumented `.syn0norm` property, which contains only unit vectors:

```
>>> w2v.init_sims()
>>> unit_king_vector = w2v.syn0norm[w2v.vocab['king'].index]
>>> numpy.linalg.norm(unit_king_vector)
0.99999994
```

The larger vector is just a scaled up version of the unit vector:

```
>>> king_vector - numpy.linalg.norm(king_vector) * unit_king_vector
array([  0.00000000e+00,  -1.86264515e-09,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  -1.86264515e-09,   0.00000000e+00,
        -7.45058060e-09,   0.00000000e+00,   3.72529030e-09,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
        ... (some lines omitted) ...
        -1.86264515e-09,  -3.72529030e-09,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00], dtype=float32)
```

Given that word similarity comparisons in Word2Vec are done by [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), it's not obvious to me what the lengths of the non-normalised vectors mean - although I assume they mean *something*, since gensim exposes them to me rather than only exposing the unit vectors in `.syn0norm`.

How are the lengths of these non-normalised Word2vec vectors generated, and what is their meaning? For what calculations does it make sense to use the normalised vectors, and when should I use the non-normalised ones?

Comment: Related: [Should I normalize word2vec's word vectors before using them?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/177905/12359)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is described in the 2015 paper [Measuring Word Significance
using
Distributed Representations of Words](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02297.pdf) by Adriaan Schakel and Benjamin Wilson. The key points:

> When a word appears
>   in different contexts, its vector gets moved in
>   different directions during updates. The final vector
>   then represents some sort of weighted average
>   over the various contexts. Averaging over vectors
>   that point in different directions typically results in
>   a vector that gets shorter with increasing number
>   of different contexts in which the word appears.
>   For words to be used in many different contexts,
>   they must carry little meaning. Prime examples of
>   such insignificant words are high-frequency stop
>   words, which are indeed represented by short vectors
>   despite their high term frequencies ...

---

> For given term frequency,
>   the vector length is seen to take values only in a
>   narrow interval. That interval initially shifts upwards
>   with increasing frequency. Around a frequency
>   of about 30, that trend reverses and the interval
>   shifts downwards.
>
> ...
>
> Both forces determining the length of a word
>   vector are seen at work here. Small-frequency
>   words tend to be used consistently, so that the
>   more frequently such words appear, the longer
>   their vectors. This tendency is reflected by the upwards
>   trend in Fig. 3 at low frequencies. High-frequency
>   words, on the other hand, tend to be
>   used in many different contexts, the more so, the
>   more frequently they occur. The averaging over
>   an increasing number of different contexts shortens
>   the vectors representing such words. This tendency
>   is clearly reflected by the downwards trend
>   in Fig. 3 at high frequencies, culminating in punctuation
>   marks and stop words with short vectors at
>   the very end.
>
> ...
>
> [image: Graph showing the trend described in the previous excerpt]
>
> Figure 3: Word vector length *v* versus term frequency
>   *tf* of all words in the hep-th vocabulary.
>   Note the logarithmic scale used on the frequency
>   axis. The dark symbols denote bin means with the
>   *k*th bin containing the frequencies in the interval
>   [2<sup>*k−1*</sup>, 2<sup>*k*</sup> − 1] with *k* = 1, 2, 3, . . .. These means
>   are included as a guide to the eye. The horizontal
>   line indicates the length *v* = 1.37 of the mean
>   vector

---

> #### 4 Discussion
>
> Most applications of distributed representations of
>   words obtained through word2vec so far centered
>   around semantics. A host of experiments have
>   demonstrated the extent to which the direction of
>   word vectors captures semantics. In this brief report,
>   it was pointed out that not only the direction,
>   but also the length of word vectors carries important
>   information. Specifically, it was shown that
>   word vector length furnishes, in combination with
>   term frequency, a useful measure of word significance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complement @user3592579's accepted answer a bit:

> How are the lengths of these non-normalised Word2vec vectors generated?

Rare words might have shorter vectors resulting from fewer updates during training ([Turian et al., 2010](https://aclanthology.org/P10-1040.pdf); [Schnabel et al., 2015](https://aclanthology.org/D15-1036.pdf)).

> For what calculations does it make sense to use the normalized vectors?

See various references mentioned [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/218729/380102). In short, normalized vectors do better in similarity and word relation tasks.

I'd also suggest reading Section 6 of ([Schnabel et al., 2015](https://aclanthology.org/D15-1036.pdf)) in addition to "Measuring Word Significance using Distributed Representations of Words" as suggested by the above answer. It reveals that the direction of word vectors does encode term frequency.